# Unit Testing and Equals/GetHashCode in entities

Tags: entity-framework, mstest

So I have created a few POCO's and currently one of them is part of a collection that I am testing. I am using MS Test and apparently when I need to compare two collections I will use CollectionsAssert.AreEquivalent(). Now in my entity besides all the properties I have overriden .Equals() and .GetHashCode() because these two are needed by CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(). My simple question is - are these two methods ok to be there?

Comment: Can you show how did you implement those methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special care needs to be taken when overriding Equals and GetHashCode as an incorrect implementation could lead to subtle bugs and performance issues that are hard to debug. If you just need them for testing a safer approach would be to implement your own AreEquivalent() method that accepts an IEqualityComparer.

Having said that EF itself doesn't rely on Equals and GetHashCode for POCO's, instead it uses the equivalents on the EntityKey for the entity.

If you do need to override these methods you could delegate to the corresponding EntityKey to get EF semantics in non-EF code that uses the entities. This approach however is not appropiate for all scenarios as it only uses the key values to establish entity identity.